# How do I loop through an html structure and replace the necessary data?

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

So basically, I am trying to generate n number pages, using different layouts from the database.

So the problem I am facing is when I am looping through the n number of pages eg. 3 pages, and for each of the pages getting the number of images as well as the content to replace, so I have 5 images in total and I in the layout I have selected I need to store 2 images per page, so that gives 3 pages in total.

So the issue is the html is stored in a variable and I need to use `str_replace()` to update the static content with the dynamic content, however the layout seems to be looping as it is running in a loop

I am fetching the dynamic content from the functions you can see in the `str_replace()` function.

```
$x=0
for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
    echo "Page Number: ".$i;
    echo "<br />";
    for($j=1;$j<=$txtimg_count;$j++){

    if(!empty($images[$x])){

        echo "Image: ".$j;
        echo "<br />";
        echo str_replace(array('<PAGE_HEAD>', '<SECTION_TITLE>', '<img id="image_'.$j.'" src="images/add-img.png" width="100%"/>', '<p id="img_data_'.$j.'"></p>', "<p>Sub text here :- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p>"), array('Section', GetSectionName($images[$x]->iMediaID), '<img id="image_'.$j.'" src="'.GetMediaName($images[$x]->iMediaID).'" width="100%"/>', '<p id="img_data_'.$j.'">'.GetMediaContent($images[$x]->iMediaID).'</p>', ""), $layout);

    }

    $x++;

}
```

`Page Number: 1
Image: 1
Image: 2
Page Number: 2
Image: 1
Image: 2
Page Number: 3
Image: 1`

This is what the output should be but the entire layout is getting looped, and a number of duplicates are showing. Is there any other solution to this issue?

**Just forgot to mention that the $layout is the HTML Structure which I am getting from the DB, updated the question below**

```
    <div class="layout-box">
      <h2><SECTION_TITLE></h2>

       <div class="img-add-box">
          <img id="image_1" src="images/add-img.png" width="100%"/>
          <button type="button" onClick="GetButtonID(this.id)" id="1" class="add-img-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

          <p id="img_data_1"></p> 
        </div>

      <h2><SECTION_TITLE></h2>

       <div class="img-add-box">
          <img id="image_2" src="images/add-img.png" width="100%"/>
          <button type="button" onClick="GetButtonID(this.id)" id="2" class="add-img-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

          <p id="img_data_2"></p> 
        </div>

    </div>
```